# Separate joined words in a string using python

Tags: python

```
"10JAN2015AirMail standard envelope from HyderabadAddress details:John Cena Palm DriveAdelaide.Also Contained:NilAction Taken:Goods referred to HGI QLD for further action.Attachments:Nil34FEB2004"
```

What I want to do is to read this string in python and separate the joined words. What I exactly want is a regular expression to separate the joined words in the string.

I want to read the above string from a file and the output should be as follows:

```
"10 JAN 2015 AirMail standard envelope from Hyderabad Address details : John Cena Palm Drive Adelaide. Also calculated: Nil Action Taken: Goods referred to USG for further action. Attachments : Nil 60 FEB 2004."
```

(Separate the joined words)

I need to write a regular expression to separate:

`'10Jan2015AirMail', 'HyderabadAddress', 'details:John', 'DriveAdelaide'`

Need a regular expression to identify joined words like above and separate them with a space in the same string like

`'10 Jan 2015 AirMail, 'Hyderabad Address', 'details : John'`

```
text = open('C:\sample.txt', 'r').read().replace("\n","").replace("\t","").replace("-",""‌​).replace("/"," ")

newtext = re.sub('[a-zA-Z0-9_:]','',text) #This regex does not work.Please assist

print text
print newtext
```

The above code does not work

Comment: What we need is evidence that you have attempted solving the problem yourself.

Comment: Have you got any attempts? You can't just post a problem and ask for a solution without first presenting your own attempt at the solution.

Comment: text = open('C:\sample.txt', 'r').read().replace("\n","").replace("\t","").replace("-","").replace("/"," ")
newtext = re.sub('[a-zA-Z0-9_:]','',text)

print text
print newtext

Answer (score 0):

I know that this solution can be done pretty much simpler classifying chars in sets (upper, lower, numeric) but I preferred to do a much more verbose solution:

```
test_text = "10JAN2015AirMail standard envelope from HyderabadAddress details:John Cena Palm DriveAdelaide.Also Contained:NilAction Taken:Goods referred to HGI QLD for further action.Attachments:Nil34FEB2004"
splitted_text = test_text.split(' ')
num = False
low = False
upp = False
result = []

for word in ss:
  new_word = ''
  if not word.isupper() and not word.islower():
    if word[0].isnumeric():
        num = True
        low = False
        upp = False
    elif word[0].islower():
        num = False
        low = True
        upp = False
    elif word[0].isupper():
        num = False
        low = False
        upp = True
    for letter in word:
      if letter.isnumeric():
        if num:
            new_word += letter
        else:
            new_word += ' ' + letter
        low = False
        upp = False
        num = True
      elif letter.islower():
        if low or upp:
            new_word += letter
        else:
            new_word += ' ' + letter
        low = True
        upp = False
        num = False
      elif letter.isupper():
        if low or num:
            new_word += ' ' + letter
        else:
            new_word += letter
        low = False
        upp = True
        num = False
      else:
        new_word += ' ' + letter
    result.append(''.join(new_word))
  else:
    result.append(word)
' '.join(result)
#'10 JAN 2015 Air Mail standard envelope from Hyderabad Address details : John Cena Palm Drive Adelaide . Also Contained : Nil Action Taken : Goods referred to HGI QLD for further action . Attachments : Nil 34 FEB 2004'
```

Sometimes one just need to be pointed int he right direction.

Comment: Thanks for that Rafael. The logic is clear by as you mentioned I am checking for more efficient way using the regex expression.

Comment: Do you want one magic regex to do it all? Or could be done with a mix of regexes?.. I could try it for further,  but that might not be pretty nor efficient.